# Show $A$ is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Suppose $A^3$ is a unitary matrix. Prove that $A$ is diagonalizable.

My attempt: Since $A^3$ is unitary, is normal and hence, diagonalizable ($\mathbb{C}$ spectral theorem). Write $A^3=PDP^{-1}$.

Case I: Suppose $D$ is invertible. Then $A=PCP^{-1}$, where $C$ is the diagonal matrix such that $c_{ii}=(d_{ii})^{\frac{1}{3}}$

Case II. Suppose $D$ is not invertible. Since the set of diagonalizable matrices $\Lambda$ is a dense subset of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, there exists a sequence $\{M_n\}\subset\Lambda$ such that $M_n\to A^3$.

Let $M_n\in K$. Since $M_n\in\Lambda$, $M_n=PD_nP^{-1}$ where $D_n$ is diagonal. Let $C_n$ be the diagonal matrix such that $c_{ii}=(d_{ii})^{\frac{1}{3}}$. So

$\begin{align}
[\text{lim}(PC_nP^{-1})]^3&=\text{lim}(PC_nP^{-1})^3\\
&=\text{lim}(PC_n^{3}P^{-1})\\
&=\text{lim}(PD_nP^{-1})\\
&=\text{lim}M_n\\
&=A^3.
\end{align}$

Thus, $A=\text{lim}(PC_nP^{-1})=P(\text{lim}C_n)P^{-1}$. Since each $C_n$ is diagonal, the limit $\text{lim}C_n$ is diagonal (the limit of the entries of $C_n$, i.e. the limit of the diagonal entries). Hence, $A$ is diagonalizable.

Questions: Does my attempt look correct? Even if it is, it seems too complicated for this problem. Does anyone have a simpler solution?

Comment: Do you mean to write $A^3 = PDP^{-1}$? If so, why would $A = PD^{-2}P^{-1}$ (in, e.g. Case I)?

Comment: Oh, yes. That was a stupid mistake on my part, $A$ wouldn't necessarily equal that. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: Maybe it works if you set $A=PD'^{3}P^{-1}$, where $D'$ is the diagonal matrix where the diagonal entries are the cubed root of the diagonal entries of $D$ above (the original diagonal matrix)?

Comment: Note that there is no Case II. Since $A^3$ is unitary it is invertible, hence $D$ _is_ invertible. (Alas we still need a correct proof for Case I.)

Comment: $A$ is always diagonalizable, since $A^3$ is unitary and that would be sufficient. proof in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to prove the following: if $A$ is invertible, then $A^3$ is diagonalizable if and only if $A$ is diagonalizable. It suffices to show that this holds for a matrix in Jordan form.

Comment: An actual correct argument.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom You ignore the fact that $A^3$ is unitary.

Comment: @msm I use the fact that $A^3$ is unitary to note that it is diagonalizable

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Then it is ignored.

Comment: @msm that's not what "ignore" means. In any case, my statement is correct, and it's enough to answer the question.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Your statement is not related to this question. It provides an answer for a similar question in which "unitary" is changed to "diagonalizable". That said, it is correct in such case.

Comment: @msm.  *"If $A^3$ is unitary, it is invertible and diagonalizable.  Because $A^3$ is both invertible and diagonalizable, $A$ must be diagonalizable.  So, if $A^3$ is unitary, then $A$ is diagonalizable."*  If you don't agree with me that this is a valid line of reasoning to reach the desired conclusion, then I can't help you.

Comment: @msm of course, I'm not going to prove an "if and only if" result here, because such a result doesn't hold.

Comment: This is new and I believe the answer should be updated. Anyway...

Answer (score 1):

$A^3$ is unitary. Hence $A^3=VDV^*$ where $D$ is diagonal and $V$ is unitary. The powers of $A^3$ can also be represented accordingly:

Hence, $A=(A^3)^{\frac{1}{3}}=VD^{\frac{1}{3}}V^*$ and $A$ is diagonalizable.

One might argue that the cubic root of a matrix is not unique and the above result is not generally true. Let's assume the matrix $A^3$ has another cube root $B$. In such case, it is impossible for $B$ to not be diagonalizable since in such case the cube of the matrix won't be unitary (proof https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1888400), so again $B$ should be diagonizable. That is $B=U\Lambda U^{-1}$ which is the desired.

Comment: Cube roots of a matrix are not unique. We definitely can't say that $A$ is unitarily diagonalizable (i.e. unitary in its own right)

Comment: Example: if $U$ is a rotation by $120$ degrees, take $$A=\pmatrix{U& 2I\\0&I}$$

Comment: It's not up to us to define $A$; we are given in the problem that $A$ is a matrix such that $A^3$ is unitary. With a proof along your lines, I could accidentally conclude that "if $x^2$ is positive, then so is $x$".

Comment: "$x^2$ is positive. Let's refer to $x$ as $x=\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$. Since $x=|x|$, $x$ must have been positive! QED"

Comment: This is not correct. It does not specify $A$.

Comment: It's true that we cannot conclude that $A=VD^{1/3}V^*$. That shows the argument in the OP is incorrect; it does not  show that $A$ is not necessarily diagonalizable.

Comment: @David C. Ullrich yes, it can be diagonalizable. But it can be other way as well.

Comment: @msm That may be so. You should _prove_ that it can be the other way.

Comment: @David C I suppose the example in the comment is a counterexample.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom In that example I don't see why $A^3$ is diagonalizable. If you'd said $A=[[U,I],[0,I]]$ then it looks to me like $A^3=I$. Did one of us drop a $2$ somewhere or something? **Also**, probably a stupid question: With either version of the example, why is it clear that $A$ is not diagonalizable?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich does the two throw things off? It's supposed to be the case that $A^3=I$. The point isn't that $A$ fails to be diagonalizable, it fails to be *unitarily* diagonalizable, so it couldn't possibly be recovered by the procedure in this question

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich the motivation for my example is that it nearly fails to commute with its transpose but satisfies $A^3=I$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, $A^3=I$ with your version; I just found the $2$ that _I_ dropped, so never mind about that. Oh: $A$ is not unitarily diagonalizable because it fails to commute with its adjoint - duh, I said it was probably a stupid question. Dunno what you mean, "nearly fails". But never mind, it's all fine.

Comment: @David Typo: should be "neatly fails". So it just fails, is what I'm saying.

Comment: I have a quick question. Would msm argument work if $A^3$ was self-adjoint, since then all eigenvalues would be real? Wouldn't the cubed root be unique?

Comment: @user124910 no. For msm's argument to work, you need to know something new about $A$ itself, not just $A^3$.  If we happened to know that both $A^3$ and $A$ were self adjoint, then this question wouldn't be particularly interesting.