# Cubic root of a unitary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find a unitary matrix whose cubic root is not diagonalizable (or equivalently find a matrix that is not diagonizable and its cube is unitary).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you want $A^3$ to be unitary.  The eigenvalues of $A$ are cube roots of the eigenvalues of $A^3$, so these are all on the unit circle.  For $A$ to be non-diagonalizable, there must be an eigenvalue $\lambda$ and nonzero vectors $u$, $v$ such that 
$$A u = \lambda u, \ A v = \lambda v + u $$
But then 
$$ A^3 u = \lambda^3 u, \ A^3 v = \lambda^3 v + 3 \lambda^2 u$$
and this is impossible if $A^3$ is unitary.